# I have oracle database table, following my table i want to insert data into my table through java but it showing ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: java, oracle

I have oracle database table, following my table i want to insert data into my table through java but it showing ORA-01843: not a valid month

```
        POLICY_NO         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
        INSURED_NAME               VARCHAR2(20) 
        POLICY_START_DATE          DATE         
        POLICY_END_DATE            DATE         
        CLAIM_STATUS               VARCHAR2(20) 
        NCB_PER                    VARCHAR2(10) 

insetIntoDBTable = "INSERT INTO details " + "VALUES ('1800/A123451','Sajid','1/1/2016','4/6/2016','policy live','90%')";
```

Comment: i also used insetIntoDBTable = "INSERT INTO details " + "VALUES ('1800/A123451','Sajid','1-Jan-2016','4-Jun-2016','policy live','90')";

Answer (score 3):

You need [to_date](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/TO_DATE.htm#SQLRF06132):

```
INSERT INTO details VALUES ('1800/A123451','Sajid', to_date('1/1/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),to_date('4/6/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'policy live','90%')
```